I want to rewrite my url for single mobile page using .htaccess
Gadgets92
    - mobiles
        - index.php
        - product.php
        - .htaccess

I have above folder structure
Also, I have registered Gadgets92 folder as gadgets92.test using Windows virtual host
In my http://gadgets92.test/mobiles/index.php file I have link to product.php file as "http://gadgets92.test/mobiles/slug".
I want to convert "http://gadgets92.test/mobiles/slug" to "http://gadgets92.test/mobiles/product.php?slug=slug" using .htaccess
I have tried
RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite rule for "/mobiles/slug" to "/mobiles/product.php?slug=slug"
RewriteRule ^mobiles/([^/]+)$ /mobiles/product.php?slug=$1 [L]



What http server are you using? How did you make sure that the http server consideres such distributed configuration files at all? Where is that file located? And is it really readable for the http server process?

Apart from that: I would expect your setup to result in an endless rewriting loop. The result you receive should actually say so. So ... what result do you receive? What do you see? I suggest you use the [END] flag instead of the [L] flag to prevent that endless rewriting loop.

I am using Apache server

I see a 404 not found error

Verify whether your .htaccess is enabled or not, by putting some garbage (random) text on top of your .htaccess and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not when you visit your page in browser. 500 error means .htaccess is enabled.

Yes, it's enabled already

Did you get 500 error as per my test?

When you reply to my question please don't forget to add mention @anubhava

What do you get when you enter http://gadgets92.test/mobiles/ URL in browser?

I put the .htaccess file to the root directory (Gadgets92) and write the following code in it.
RewriteEngine On

# Exclude "index.php" and "action.php" from rewriting in each directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(mobiles|laptops|watches|televisions|headsets)/index\.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(mobiles|laptops|watches|televisions|headsets)/action\.php$

RewriteRule ^(mobiles|laptops|watches|televisions|headsets)/([^/]+)/?$ $1/product.php?slug=$2 [QSA,L]

Now it accepts slugs write it as product.php?slug=slug internally. It does not rewrite other files in those folders except for product.php.
